# is there a way to keep and update a "list" in a %let variable?

Tags: sas, global

Still pretty new (and struggling!) to SAS, here's something that I'd really like to be able to do but just can't figure out: keep and update/append to a list throughout a SAS script.

Situation: my job involves creating/sorting datasets based on a large database, for others to use. E.g. we receive a list of selection criteria and variables requested that we use to create a dataset for research purposes. Some of the requested variables will be 'delivery ready' within our database, others we have to compute/create in the requested format. We write SAS scripts that document the entire process from selection to writing of the dataset for delivery. Which means that towards the end there is a step were we select from all the variables in the dataset that we work in, only the variables that we want to deliver to our 'clients'. What I would really like to do is to 'build' the list of variables for delivery 'as I go', i.e. add the name of each variable that I created or have verified to be ready for delivery to a list called "varstodeliver", so that at the end I can simply tell it to select all vars in "varstodeliver". Is this possible?

This is how far I've got:

```
%let varstodeliver = IDvar;
%put &varstodeliver; * prints IDvar;

data _null_;
 call symputx("varstodeliver", catx(" ", vname(&varstodeliver.), "var1 var2"));
run;

%put &varstodeliver; * prints IDvar var1 var2 ;
```

Note that I ended up resorting to the use of 'vname( )' in order to get the actual name stored in &varstodeliver. So far so good, but if I then attempt to add a fourth variable name (or rather: a third addition, since the previous addition was two variablenames in one go), it stalls, due to too many levels of &varstodeliver:

```
data _null_;
 call symputx("varstodeliver", catx(" ", vname(&varstodeliver), "var3"));
run;
```

ERROR: The VNAME function call has too many arguments.

Input or ideas how else to keep a running tally are very welcome!!

p.s. among the things I've tried is this:

```
data _null_;
 call symputx("varsteleveren", catx(" ", vlist(vname(&varsteleveren.(*))), "var3"));
run;
```

which returns: 
ERROR: Undeclared array referenced: var2.
ERROR: The ARRAYNAME[*] specification requires an array.
ERROR: The VNAME function call has too many arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add names of variables to macro variable and keep them all, you can use `%let`:

```
%let varstodeliver = IDvar;
%put &=varstodeliver;
```

> VARSTODELIVER=IDvar

```
%let varstodeliver= &varstodeliver var1 var2;
%put &=varstodeliver;
```

> VARSTODELIVER=IDvar var1 var2

```
%let varstodeliver= &varstodeliver var3;
%put &=varstodeliver;
```

> VARSTODELIVER=IDvar var1 var2 var3

Comment: well this is silly.. I would have sworn that I tried that without joy but clearly ermm not. Thank you Alexey!

Comment: @t_awkr You might have forgotten to create the macro variable to start which might have caused you to attempt to store the literal characters `&varstodeliver` into the macro variable. That would lead to recursion errors.